# Using Blender's GUI application from WSL2

Tags: blender, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xserver

Recently a fellow intern finished his internship. For this internship, he wrote some automated fluid simulations in Blender on Linux. I am a Windows user, and my only option for this is running WSL(2).
Everything runs great, except for the last step (which is most important to my work). This last step requires the Blender GUI to run.

I am currently using VcXrsv, installed by following this tutorial: https://dannyda.com/2020/06/15/how-to-launch-gui-software-programs-from-windows-subsystem-for-linux-2-wsl2-how-to-convert-from-wsl-1-to-wsl-2/. I have made sure to allow native OpenGL.

I've managed to run other GUI applications using this x-server , but Blender will not run, instead giving me this error:

```
Read prefs: /home/pcsmet/.config/blender/2.90/config/userpref.blend
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5220:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Error! Unsupported graphics card or driver.
A graphics card and driver with support for OpenGL 3.3 or higher is required.
The program will now close.
Error: Not freed memory blocks: 14567, total unfreed memory 5.376877 MB
```

I've read about being able to use your (nvidia) graphics card if you enter the Windows Insiders build + install nvidia's special WSL2 drivers, but I've also read some forum posts about OpenGL not working on WSL2. Also, I'm afraid of Win10's updates' ability to brick pc's, so I'd prefer not to enter the Windows Insiders programme.

Simply, my questions is this: **Is it possible to run Blender GUI through WSL2, and if so, how?**

I am far from a Linux/WSL wizzkid, and getting this to work is fairly vital to my internship, so any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Blender is available to windows users as well. So no need to run inside a VM

Comment: @pouya the software for the fluid simulations only run on Linux. Therefore running on windows is not an option

Comment: How about running your fluid simulation package under WSL and write a wrapper systemd service around that then you should be able to query the service on windows and pass the results to the blender.

Answer (score 0):

It will be possible without X extra XServer like VcXrsv once Microsoft finishes support for graphical applications within WSL2. It will probably take another couple of months, but judging from the demo at the XDC 2020 conference in September, they are pretty close.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/whats-new-in-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux-september-2020/#gui-apps

In this video, they show Blender running in a virtual machine, in WSL 2 with X Server, and natively on Windows 10. So it is already possible to run Blender in WSL 2 with properly configured X Server.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ss71ldXkmQs

Comment: Now I know that it _is_ possible, I still need to know how. Would you happen to know how to properly configure an X Server for Blender?

Comment: I do not know exactly how to do it, but I suspect that it is related to the fact that Blender uses OpenGL with hardware acceleration. So it is harder to run than the regular X Window application, which only uses normal Xlib function calls. Maybe this thread will give you some useful hints of how to set it:
https://superuser.com/questions/1487555/how-to-troubleshoot-opengl-on-ubuntu-under-windows-10-wsl